# Addfrag is not accepting for more than one

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import com.hrm.toolbar.AddressToolbar;

import com.hrm.toolbar.EmergencyToolbar;

public class ToolbarMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_toolbar);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new AddressToolbar(), "Address");
    adapter.addFrag(new EmergencyToolbar(), "Emergency");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }



    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
The method addFrag(Fragment, String) in the type ToolbarMenu.ViewPagerAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (AddressToolbar, String)
```

AddressToolbar

```
public class AddressToolbar extends Fragment {

     public AddressToolbar() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.address_toolbar, container, false);
        }
}
```

Comment: Does `AddressToolbar` extends `Fragment` ? If possible please share the full stacktrace.

Comment: check that you are importing support v4 fragment in both classes

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;                                                    I added this import Statement in both still it shows error

Comment: @PreethiRajan check that you have removed "import android.app.Fragment"

Comment: Yea i replaced it with android.support.v4.app.Fragment;